# .net core options to connect to JDBC driver

Tags: c#, .net, jdbc, asp.net-core, odbc

I am trying to find out options to connect to a database that is hosted on cloud (Cloud Foundry) and is available as a service. The DB is offered through JDBC driver. I am trying to write a `.netcore` application (fine with any framework though) to connect to the DB service.

I had referenced the `.netcore` options and don't find a way to connect to such services. They have provided option to connect to Azure - but, that's a SQL DB. Request for a direction to try out the options:

- ODBC - Can I try ODBC - JDBC bridge option?
- Oracle Managed Dataservice - Not sure if this can help for the cloud foundry option.
- Should I consider moving to .NET Framework instead of .NET Core?

The DB I am trying is a relational DB.

Comment: The main reason for me to go with .net core is its ease for cloud foundry deployment. If the situation insist, i would go with the framework approach - hence the statement. I would like to try with .net core first.

Comment: Well, EF Core has a number of database providers that should get you started... Here is a link for EF Core's database providers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/ -- note that depending on the ORM you want to use, your options will vary greatly especially if you're only working with .NET Core.

Comment: I did have a look at the link before, however, not all the relational DBs are supported at the moment. Hence was wondering if there is a generic way?

Comment: This is my favorite resource online regarding your subject. Take a look: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/09/net-core-data-access/

Comment: Thank you, @Svek for the link. I am having a look at it. The initial view states that most of the ORMs are for SQL servers. Anyways, let me look deep.

Comment: The blog post is a bit dusty, so make sure you read the comments sections. There's quite a bit of activity on the ODBC end; along with a lot of recommendations to go with mono (for now)

Comment: JDBC is for Java (and other JVM-based languages), so using JDBC from C# would be sub-optimal

Answer (score 3):

Connecting a C# app to a JDBC (Java) data source requires a bridge of some kind, possibly multiple bridges stacked atop each other.  Examples include this, with two API translations (from [ADO.NET to JDBC](https://www.openlinksw.com/), and from JDBC to DBMS) --

```
C# ADO.NET app
-> OpenLink Enterprise Edition Generic Client ADO.NET Provider 
   ... TCP/IP ...
       -> OpenLink Enterprise Edition Request Broker & 
          Bridge Agent for JDBC Data Sources
          -> JDBC Driver
```

-- and this, with three API translations (from [ADO.NET to ODBC](https://uda.openlinksw.com/dotnet-jdbc-mt/), and [ODBC to JDBC](https://uda.openlinksw.com/dotnet-odbc-st/), and from JDBC to DBMS) --

```
C# ADO.NET app
-> OpenLink Lite Edition ADO.NET Provider for ODBC Data Sources
   -> OpenLink Lite Edition ODBC Driver for JDBC Data Sources
      -> JDBC Driver
```

These Bridges (Enterprise Edition [ADO.NET to JDBC](https://www.openlinksw.com/), Lite Edition [ADO.NET to ODBC](https://uda.openlinksw.com/dotnet-jdbc-mt/), and Lite Edition [ODBC to JDBC](https://uda.openlinksw.com/dotnet-odbc-st/)) come from my employer, [OpenLink Software](https://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-jdbc-st/).  There are other options.